# What are the values of the integrals?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Here is the problem:

> Let $R>0, \varepsilon>0$. For $t\geq 0$ define
>   $$ \psi^+_\varepsilon(t) := \left\{
>      \begin{array}{ll}
>        1 & 0 \leq t \leq R\\
>        1+(R-t)/\varepsilon & R<t \leq R+\varepsilon\\
>        0 & R+\varepsilon<t
>      \end{array}
>    \right.$$
>   and $\psi^-_\varepsilon(t) := \psi^+_\varepsilon(t+\varepsilon) $
>
> Find the values of $$\int_{\mathbb R^n} \psi^\pm_\varepsilon (\|x\|)dx$$

First, I tried to draw the construction in question (for small $N$) and to find the integral geometrically yet the calculations quickly became messy and unmanageable.

Then I was told there is a shortcut based on symmetry (I guess) but I can't see it.

Comment: Maybe I don't get it right, but $\psi$ seems a simple function with two constant pieces and a linear one. The meaning of $\psi^-$ is no clear to me, but otherwise - where's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\psi^\pm_\epsilon(\|x\|)$ only on the distance from the origin, so changing to spherical coordinates gives us
$$\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb R^n}\psi^+(\|x\|)dx 
&=\int_0^\infty A_n(r)\psi^+(r)dr\\
&=\frac{2\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2)}\int_0^\infty r^{n-1}\psi^+(r)dr\\
&=\frac{2\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2)}\left(\int_0^R r^{n-1}dr + \int_R^{R+\epsilon} \left(\frac{R+\epsilon}{\epsilon}r^{n-1}-\frac{1}{\epsilon}r^n\right)dr\right)\\
&=\frac{2\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2)}\left(\frac{R^n}{n} + \frac{(R+\epsilon)((R+\epsilon)^n-R^n)}{n\epsilon} - \frac{(R+\epsilon)^{n+1}-R^{n+1}}{(n+1)\epsilon}\right)\\
&=\frac{2\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2)}\left(\frac{(R+\epsilon)^n}{n}+\frac{R((R+\epsilon)^n-R^n)}{n\epsilon}- \frac{(R+\epsilon)^{n+1}-R^{n+1}}{(n+1)\epsilon}\right)
\end{align}$$
where $A_n(r)=\frac{2\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2)}r^{n-1}$ is the surface area of the $(n-1)$-sphere of radius $r$. If $\epsilon\le R$, we can compute the integral of $\psi^-$ easily from that of $\psi^+$, as
$$\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb R^n}\psi^-(\|x\|)dx 
&=\int_0^\infty A_n(r)\psi^-(r)dr\\
&=\int_\epsilon^\infty A_n(r)\psi^+(r)dr\\
&=\int_{\mathbb R^n}\psi^+(\|x\|)dx - \int_0^\epsilon A_n(r)\psi^+(r)dr\\
&=\int_{\mathbb R^n}\psi^+(\|x\|)dx - \frac{2\pi^{n/2}}{n\Gamma(n/2)}\epsilon^n dr
\end{align}$$
Otherwise it's probably easiest to just repeat the process for $\psi^+$.